# Error with Drop constraint in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

After executing this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE Instagram

CREATE TABLE Users (
    Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    ProfilePicture VARBINARY(MAX),
    LastLoginTime DATETIME, 
    IsDelited BIT 
)  

INSERT INTO Users ([UserName], [Password], [ProfilePicture], [LastLoginTime], 
[IsDelited]) VALUES
('Stamat','12r3',NULL,CONVERT(datetime,'22-05-2018',103),0),
('Gosho','125463',NULL,CONVERT(datetime,'22-06-2018',103),0),
('Pesho','123453',NULL,CONVERT(datetime,'27-05-2018',103),0),
('Vankata','123354',NULL,CONVERT(datetime,'24-03-2018',103),0),
('Dani','12354556',NULL,CONVERT(datetime,'15-04-2018',103),0)

ALTER TABLE Users DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD
```

I'm receiving this error:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   'PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD' is not a constraint.
>   Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 21
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: This looks to be SQL Server not MySQL..So i've changed the tags.

Comment: The code and the error message you have shared in your question has nothing to do with each other, can you share the code you are using to drop the constraint?

Comment: You might had not copied the complete code.

Comment: Your error also says "see previous errors" yet you haven't included said previous errors.

Comment: @Larnu - `PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD' is not a constraint` is the previous error.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, other than the missing `USE Instagram;` before creating the table. If you are really running only that script and getting these errors, it could be due to an issue in a DDL trigger.

Comment: 21 Line? May by DDL trigger

Comment: @DanGuzman - it's not my question :D

Comment: But it is relevant, as the DDL trigger could be in the database you were previously connected to, as you didn't connect to the `Instagram` database.

Comment: This is the final line:

   ALTER TABLE Users
      DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD

Comment: Try this instead - 
`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE Users
  DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Users__3214EC07D90D90CD
END;`

Comment: Considering you don't create a constraint in your SQL, why are you expecting that you could drop one?

Comment: If you drop and recreate your table, AND you are letting SQL auto assign the constraint name, it will be different each time. Explicitly name the constraint and this will be much more straightforward.

Comment: @StanislavGeorgiev, how did you determine the constraint name for the `ALTER TABLE`? The actual one is auto-generated because no explict name was specified and will differ. The best practice is to explicitly name constraint to facilitate subsequent DDL.

Comment: The code in the question runs fine without error.  This question should either be closed or edited to show the code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be that you are trying to drop the auto-named primary key constraint on this table. Since it was given a generic name by SQL Server, it will be different each time you create this constraint. I have modified your code to explicitly create and name the PK constraint:

```
CREATE DATABASE Instagram

CREATE TABLE Users (
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    ProfilePicture VARBINARY(MAX),
    LastLoginTime DATETIME, 
    IsDelited BIT, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Instagram_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)
```

Now you can drop the constraint with a slightly modified version of your script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'PK_Instagram_Id') 
BEGIN 
    ALTER TABLE Users 
    DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Instagram_Id
END
```